# How to fly leaves in Stylized Fantasy Tree?

Tags: add-on, geometry-nodes

I just downloaded Stylized Fantasy Tree Add-Ons, but have no idea how to let leaves fly/fall. I don't see any option for it. Is it possible to do it in the option or should I make it?

[image]

If you watch this video, you will be able to understand what I mean.
https://youtu.be/uL3qQ4Rwqbw

Comment: You should post some screenshots of the plugin, settings you've tried, what you expect the outcome to be. Right now no one except people who are highly proficient at this specific addon could help you now. If you post more info maybe we could help you figure it out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry. I'm a newbie on Blender, so my question might confuse you. I just uploaded the screenshot and hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to the gumroad page of the developer of that addon, it doesn't seem like that's a built in feature just yet.

[image: developer gumroad info]

You would be able to do this but it would require you to create your own particle system with the leaves that are generated by the addon.

Here's a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT_Tr_jzrE8) on how you would do that. Obviously it won't be a 1:1 tutorial but it will give you an idea of the process. It's relatively straightforward.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the details and the tutorial video.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answered your question can you mark it as such?

Comment: How to mark it? Sorry, I'm so newbie here.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour